# set environment variables for aws lambda execution environment

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, environment-variables, aws-cdk

How can I access environment variables in python global scope, outside the lambda function itself?
In the cdk stack code I can define a function like this for example:

```
get_games_lambda = PythonFunction(
            self,
            'GetGamesHandler',
            function_name='GetGames',
            entry='../server',
            runtime=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_8,
            handler='get_games',
            index='app.py',
            environment={
                "rds": 'arn:aws:secretsmanager:...',
            }
        )
```

but I want the env var to be accessible in the code that's run in the top of the file where the lambda function is.

app.py file:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, func, select, and_, text
engine = create_engine(<here I want to access the env variable>)


# the lambda function:
def get_games(event, context):
     ...
```

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "at the top of the file where the lambda function is"? The CDK code in your question is kind of irrelevant here. The way you deploy your Lambda function (CDK code or Terraform or AWS Console or whatever) should have no bearing on your Lambda function's code being able to access the environment variables.

Comment: @MarkB I added the relevant code to the question

Comment: Have you tried accessing the environment variable there, at that line of code? Did you have an error message or something? It should work just fine. There is nothing currently stopping that from working exactly like you want it to.

Comment: I'll try. So I define the var in on of the lambda functions in the file, and it should accessible everywhere in the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `engine = create_engine(<here I want to access the env variable>)`

This code will execute once, when Lambda loads your module into a container which will eventually execute your function. You can tell containers from each other, for instance, by looking into their CloudWatch log names.

Per Lambda philosophy, it's not any of your business when and how this global code gets executed, and you should design your functions without any assumptions about it. It should be read-only shared state.

Realistically, it does matter (expensive things like initializing connection pools and similar should go here, so they are executed once per container rather than once per invocation). Lambda invocation involving executing this global code is called "cold start" and there are many clever tricks to make it faster.

That said, this global code has access to the container's environment, the same way the function code does, which is populated with the values from your Lambda function's definition.

If you do something like this:

```py
rds = os.environ['rds']
url = boto3.client('secretsmanager').get_secret_value(SecretId = rds)
engine = create_engine(url)
```

, it should have access to the variable you previously defined in your construct.

You can check in the AWS console if this value made it to the Lambda's settings after deployment.

Comment: If I call a lambda function that doesn't have the 'rds' var defined, I get timeout exception.

Comment: @RonyTesler: I'm really sorry that it happens, but it doesn't seem to be related to what you originally asked. It looks like you can read the variable when it's set. If you want the timeout problem solved, please create another question with its detailed description and code. Thank you!

Comment: When I add the env variable, the timeout is solved, that's why it does look related.

Comment: @RonyTesler: I'm not saying it's unrelated. I'm saying "my lambda can't read environment" and "my lambda times out" should be in different posts, and the environment thing seems to have been solved.

Comment: Is there a way to define an env var for a group of lambda or I have to define it separately for each one?

Comment: @RonyTesler: only separately. You're using cdk so it should not be a problem replicating it to every construct.